# Work with GIT on remote site instead of local

Tags: eclipse, git, repository, egit

I have to work on a project that is on a remote GIT repository. I have a development environment accessible via ssh: I would use git on it, but I like Eclipse EGit package so I would know if there's a way to connect my Eclipse with the remote cloned repository.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the network, you might be able to mount the remote filesystem locally and use Eclipse to access the code. This will not be great on slow network.

Alternatively you can tar up the source and just copy it locally, then periodically copy to the server.

If you say that you have the development environment accessible via ssh then how will eclipse help you if it isn't in a development environment? Wouldn't you need to recreate your development environment locally as well?

You can install a remote desktop solution like NoMachine and run eclipse on the remote machine.

Please provide more details.